# Samsung Smart TV IME destroy

Tags: ime, samsung-smart-tv

I have a problem with Samsung Smart TV IME.

When it is shown, INPUT has focus. In 2012 and 2013 $(input).blur() works fine to destroy IME. But in 2011 its only hides IME keyboard and when you press  down or up IME shows again.

Keys handled to scene, not to anchor, so I can`t focus other element.

How correctly blur input for 2011 devices??

Answer (score 0):

try this:

inputElement.blur();
document.body.focus();